# Convert JSON to CSV file placed into Sdcard

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, android-sdcard

We are developing `Phonegap` app.We need `SqLite` Db data placed into `SDCard`.We did `sqLite` Data convert into `JSON` String.now we send to `SDCard`.Using this link [File API in PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

We code this json data placed into SDCard

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    //alert("seeeeee1");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    alert("seeeeee2");
    fileSystem.root.getFile("forTEST.csv", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    alert("seeeeee3");
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    alert("set");
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
    };
writer.write(JSONData);
}
```

But when we open it's `CSV` file in my mobile.it's `JSON` format

```
[
  {
    "items": "BODYLINESUPER",
    "descriptions": "100mg",
    "umo": "CTN",
    "qty": 7,
    "price": 1093.55,
    "lineamount": 7654.85,
    "customerid": "ARU007",
    "tdate": "2015-4-7",
    "orderId": "Himansu15",
  }
]
```

but We need Table format in `CSV` file.like

```
items         descriptions umo qty price  lineamount customerid tdate  orderId  
BODYLINESUPER  100mg       CTN  7  1093.55  7654.85   ARU007  2015-4-7 Himansu15
```

this line Data send to CSV file

```
writer.write(JSONData);
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please create a model class Item.
2. Create a array list with same item class type.
3. Get all data from database in item class object and put in array list.
4. After pasring json create a csv file in sd card.

5  Write all array list data into csv file.

Comment: we don't have internet in this case for Parse server .We need SqLite Db data Placed into CSV file in table format .please help me

Comment: Please guide me don't know about create model class Item. We have only SqLite Data convert into JSON object Please guide me

Comment: We write data into csv file as you said .it's working nice.Now we have two array List now we need data post csv file like List1  into Sheet1 and List2 into Sheet2 Please guide me